# SSDT Circular reference: Complex project

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools, circular-reference

I have a fairly complex setup with eight databases on a server each referencing each other (about every database referencing each other), giving way to quite a complex web. The design is far from ideal, but unfortunately this is something we have to work with.

We need to create a SSDT solution to facilitate CI/CD

The whole project needs to be deployed from scratch on a new instance and I am trying to get my head around this, as I have limited SSDT knowledge for a project this scale.

The approaches I consider are as follows:
1) Split objects into shared objects, and reference the shared objects. This seems to be a nightmare to implement, as we would require different layers because of the complex web of references. (shared object referencing other shared objects). Also how do we deploy such a project on a blank server?
2) Create stubs for each object in a project being referenced by other objects, and make a database reference to these. This seems to be the easiest option, although it seems that if the object the stub is based on gets changed, the stubs also needs to be maintained otherwise the project will break. Is this the right assumption?
3) Only create stubs for projects required to compile (eg. tables referenced by views in other databases), and ignore warning references. I am leaning towards this route as the stubs will be much smaller and project easier to maintain, but I hate to ignore referencewarnings..

If we deploy using the stubs option, do we need to deploy the stubs first and then delete them after successful deployment?

Another (more straightforward question). What is the best way to deploy logins, users and object permissions ?

Thanks for replying.

Comment: I'd probably use DB References in your case - store those in a common repo and have everything else point to them using relative references. The good thing is that the most important objects tend to rarely change and you can update the shared dacpac when needed. DON'T try to handle logins/users - put permissions in DB roles and assign those later.  Initial deploy might be easiest w/ a shell of a DB or to run w/out transactions/rollbacks to just let things fail, then come back around and re-deploy. https://schottsql.wordpress.com/all-ssdt-articles/

Comment: And I know some will say to go to the work of creating everything depending on the prior partial DBs, but that does tend to be a lot of work for not as much payoff in many cases. Yes, you get a nice clean deploy, but a very complex setup. I had a similar situation and found for the most part I could deploy 2 databases (with some errors), then all the rest worked, then I circled around to "finish" the first two databases - for an initial deploy. In practice - I think we just did a backup/restore and started from there. :)

Comment: This is a great article about complex database projects. [A Complex Database Project](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SQL+Server+Data+Tools+(SSDT)/125435/). It uses DB References. You could include referenced objects in Pre-deployment script as a blue-print to be created before deployment, and then dropped in post deployment.

Comment: Thanks Peter. Great advice. Will leave out Users/Logins for now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is too broad but these are few suggestions:

1. You can't do anything with circular reference. There are some ways to workaround it but all of them are "hacky" and most probably will introduce more problems than to solve your problem. So try to move objects in so manner that there is only one way dependency;
2. Use synonyms for ALL cross database objects, so there supposed to be no straight reference outside database;
3. I agree with Peter Schott that it is better to ignore logins and users for now as handling them in SSDT is a bit of pain and you need to have good expertise on SSDT to make it working properly.